# how to load the json data to mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have the following json file:

```
[
    {
        color: "red",
        value: "#f00"
    },
    {
        color: "green",
        value: "#0f0"
    },
    {
        color: "blue",
        value: "#00f"
    },
    {
        color: "cyan",
        value: "#0ff"
    },
    {
        color: "magenta",
        value: "#f0f"
    },
    {
        color: "yellow",
        value: "#ff0"
    },
    {
        color: "black",
        value: "#000"
    }
]
```

How can I load the data into a table using MongoDB?

Comment: Reading the mongodb documents can be a good start

Comment: Basically you open a mongo shell and type db.collection.insert(...). But like @SarathNair said - RTFM

Comment: @Kunal is this a valid json?

Comment: Sorry if I am rude, but this question is not yet worthy of answering. Please, show us what you have tried, where do you fail and etc. StackOverflow is not a place for how-to questions (see [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) ), there are a plenty of resources in internet for that, including the official documentation of mongodb where you should be starting from.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with help of  **[insert()](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/method/db.collection.insert/)** or **[save()](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/method/db.collection.save/)**
Please read above links.

Also first see if your json is valid.

[here](http://jsonlint.com/) you can check

```
db.collection.insert(
  your valid json
)
```

Comment: strictly speaking that's not JSON, it's just a JS object literal

Comment: i see, I thought its json

Comment: No, JSON is specifically a tightly specified _serialisation_ format, that happens to be parseable just like a JS object literal.

Comment: @thanks for that knowledge

Answer (score 0):

Here are some references:

Tutorial to insert multiple documents

https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/insert-documents/

Importing data from CSV with mongoimport

https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/program/mongoimport/

Answer (score 0):

```
mongoimport --db <dbname> --collection <collection-name> < <json-filename>
mongoimport --db <dbname> --collection <collection-name> --file <json-filename>
```